# Disable WildFly 13 management console

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-13

What is the proper way to disable the management console in WildFly 13? I set the `console-enabled="false"` attribute on the `http-interface`, but after running WildFly 13 I still see the management interface being deployed.

[image: Snippet of standalone.xml and WildFly 13 log]

Answer (score 3):

That is correct way to disable admin console.

Management interface is different thing, it is a backbone of the server that allows the management/administrator/monitoring etc.
For example interface so for CLI can connect to server (+ many other things)

by default it is locked down and exposed only on local host so it cannot be accessed from remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable and disable the management console by two ways:

1. Setting management port to zero in the configuration(Standalone) file

   ```
   <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:0}"/>
   ```
2. Connect to CLI utility using $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh script and execute these commands

**Enable:**

```
/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface:writeattribute(name=console-enabled,value=true)
```

**Disable:**

```
/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface:writeattribute(name=console-enabled,value=false
```

Comment: Setting the management port to 0 doesn't work with Wildfly 13

Comment: Setting the port to `0` there will make WildFly assign a random port for the management interface on start up.